# Application of Chebyshev's inequality demonstration

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, random-variables

I'm trying to prove that:

> If $X$ it's a random variable then:
>
> $P(|X|>=\epsilon)=<\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}E[X^2]$

My first try is:

If we call $1_{A}(x)=1$  ; if x $\in A$

and   $1_{A}(x)=0$  ; if x $\notin A$ Then:

$E[X^2]=E[X^2*1_{|X|<\epsilon}(x) + X^2*1_{|X|\geq\epsilon}(x)] \geq E[X^2*1_{|X|\geq\epsilon}(x)]\geq E[\epsilon^2*1_{|X|\geq\epsilon}(x)]=\epsilon^2 E[1_{|X|\geq\epsilon}]=\epsilon^2 P(|X|\geq\epsilon)$

So we got what the desired result.

But I'm not sure if $E[1_{|X|\geq\epsilon}]=P(|X|\geq\epsilon)$ it's ok, or the entire proof.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Everything looks fine, except $1_{|X| \le \epsilon}$ should be $1_{|X|<\epsilon}$ in one of your early steps.

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you.